# Devise not generating paths (rake routes shows everything as expected)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, refinerycms

I have a Rails app with Devise  / omniauth and the paths for devise are not being recognized for some reason. When I use for example "app_user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)" I get undefined method error. Same for all other paths..

```
rake routes
```

returns this:

```
                 dev_section POST     /dev_section(.:format)                       custom_actions#dev_section
      new_app_user_session GET      /app_users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
          app_user_session POST     /app_users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
  destroy_app_user_session DELETE   /app_users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
app_user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /app_users/auth/:provider(.:format)        app_users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter|google_oauth2/}
app_user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /app_users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) app_users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter|google_oauth2)
         app_user_password POST     /app_users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
     new_app_user_password GET      /app_users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
    edit_app_user_password GET      /app_users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                             PUT      /app_users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
     app_user_registration POST     /app_users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
 new_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
edit_app_user_registration GET      /app_users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                             PUT      /app_users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE   /app_users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
```

in routes.rb I have:

```
  devise_for :app_users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "app_users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

All omniauth controllers are built according to Devise examples..  What can be wrong?

*** Edit ***

I realized it might be worth mentioning, that I am using RefineryCMS..

devise.rb looks like this:

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"  

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    Devise.setup do
      require 'devise/orm/active_record'
    end
  end  

  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]  

  config.case_insensitive_keys = []  

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]  

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10  

  config.password_length = 4..128  

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours  

  config.sign_out_via = :delete    
  config.router_name = :refinery
end
```

Comment: have you setup Facebook APPID and APP_SECRET in config? and did u try :facebook with a smaller `f`?

Comment: oh sort, it's a typo - I actually do have smaller f